# Type Error when trying to use threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

quite confused about why I am getting a type error.

I'm trying to get this code to run every x amount of time but the second time it runs it's hitting an error. the error is :

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1180, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: parseXML() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xmlFile'"
```

I think it's got something to do with how I am setting up parseXML! super confused.

```
from lxml import etree
import urllib.request
import csv
import threading

#Pickle is not needed
#append to list next

def handleLeg(leg):
   # print this leg as text, or save it to file maybe...
   text = etree.tostring(leg, pretty_print=True)
   # also process individual elements of interest here if we want
   tagsOfInterest=["noTrafficTravelTimeInSeconds", "lengthInMeters", "departureTime", "trafficDelayInSeconds"]  # whatever
   #list to use for data analysis
   global data
   data = []
   #create header dictionary that includes the data to be appended within it. IE, Header = {TrafficDelay[data(0)]...etc
   for child in leg:
       if 'summary' in child.tag:
          for elem in child:
              for item in tagsOfInterest:
                  if item in elem.tag:
                      data.append(elem.text)


def parseXML(xmlFile):
   #Parse the xml
   threading.Timer(5.0, parseXML).start()
   with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.tomtom.com/routing/1/calculateRoute/-37.79205923474775,145.03010268799338:-37.798883995180496,145.03040309540322:-37.807106781970354,145.02895470253526:-37.80320743019992,145.01021142594075:-37.7999012967757,144.99318476311566:?routeType=shortest&key=xxx&computeTravelTimeFor=all") as fobj:
       xml = fobj.read()

   root = etree.fromstring(xml)

   for child in root:
       if 'route' in child.tag:
           handleLeg(child)
           # Write CSV file
           with open('datafile.csv', 'w') as fp:
            writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=' ')
            # writer.writerow(["your", "header", "foo"])  # write header
            writer.writerows(data)
           """for elem in child:
               if 'leg' in elem.tag:
                   handleLeg(elem)
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
   parseXML("xmlFile")

with open('datafile.csv', 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, quotechar='"')
    # next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    data_read = [row for row in reader]

print(data_read)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set up the `threading.Timer` you are telling it to call `parseXML` without any arguments. It should look something like this instead:

```
threading.Timer(5.0, parseXML, ["xmlFile"]).start()
```

Comment: this works better but instead of getting an error it's just not running

Comment: any idea how to get it to run continuously?

Comment: @MichaelHolborn Not from what you've given me. You should probably post a new question since this has become a different problem.